# Tricky operation involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, real-numbers, radicals, fractions

Consider the following chain of equations, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 3$:

$$
\mathbb{i}^{-n}\cdot 2^{n/2} = (\sqrt{-1})^{-n}\cdot 2^{n/2} =(-1)^{-n/2}\cdot 2^{n/2} = \frac{1}{(-1)^{n/2}} \cdot 2^{n/2} \, \mathrm{.}
$$

As far as I know, all of them are true. However, the following is not always true, according to Mathematica:

$$
\frac{1}{(-1)^{n/2}} \cdot 2^{n/2} = \left( \frac{2}{-1} \right)^{n/2} \, \mathrm{.}
$$

Why not??

Not a difficult question, I guess, but I cannot see why the last equation is either true or false depending on the value of $n$.

For instance, for $n=5$:

$$
\frac{2^{5/2}}{(-1)^{5/2}}=-\left(-\frac{2}{1}\right)^{5/2}  \, \mathrm{,}
$$

while, for $n=6$:

$$
\frac{2^{6/2}}{(-1)^{6/2}}= \left(-\frac{2}{1}\right)^{6/2} \, \mathrm{.}
$$

I thought that the equivalence

$$\frac{a^m}{b^m} = \left( \frac{a}{b} \right)^m $$

was universally true, but it seems that it only works with real numbers?

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ only applies when $x,y$ are positive numbers.  It thus follows that $(\sqrt{xy})^n=(\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y})^n$ if and only if $x,y$ are positive numbers.  If not, this statement cannot be made.

The equivalence of $\frac{1}{{(-1)}^\frac{n}{2}}2^{n/2}=(\frac{2}{-1})^{n/2}$ cannot be stated here because $-1$ is negative.

So if $n$ is even, then $\frac{n}{2}$ is a whole number and you avoid the problem arising with taking a square root.  However, if not, then the equality will not hold.

Answer (score 1):

As you (probably) know, when you take a complex number $z$ and elevate to a real power $s$ : $w=z^s$ you obtain a complex number $w$ that , in polar form has 
$|w|=|z|^s$ and $\angle w= s \angle z$.
But the angle $s \angle z$ get then reduced modulo $2\pi$.
That means that, in reversing  the operation, there are different values of $z$ for which $z^s=w\; \to \; z=w^{1/s}$, i.e. $z= |w|^{1/s} \exp(arg(w)/s + i 2k\pi/s)$.
Taking only one of them, the *principal value* which is the value programmed by default in the various CAS, does not allow you to do further "manipulations" if not carefully checking the conditions: thus the *principal* root of a product might well not be the product of the *principal* roots of the single terms.

Read for example [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Algebraic_formula).

In particular $\sqrt{-1}= \pm i$, so $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is one of, the principal, roots.

But, taking *only the principal value* leads to incongruities:
$$
1 = \sqrt 1  = \sqrt {\left( { - 1} \right)\left( { - 1} \right)}  = \left( {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,2} } \right)^{\,1/2} \quad  \ne \quad \sqrt {\left( { - 1} \right)} \sqrt {\left( { - 1} \right)}  = \left( {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,1/2} } \right)^{\,2}  = i^{\,2}  =  - 1
$$
and (as happens in your example)
$$
\matrix{
   {{1 \over {\sqrt { - 1} }} = \left( {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,1/2} } \right)^{\, - 1}  = {1 \over i} =  - i} & {\quad  \ne \quad } & {\sqrt {{1 \over { - 1}}}  = \sqrt { - 1}  = \left( {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\, - 1} } \right)^{\,1/2}  = i}  \cr 
 } 
$$
but that does not happens if we take **all the roots**, e.g.
$$
\matrix{
   {{1 \over {\sqrt { - 1} }} = 1\;e^{\, - \left( {i\pi /2 + ik\pi } \right)}  = e^{\, - i\pi /2 + ik\pi }  =  \mp i} & {\quad  = \quad } & {\sqrt {{1 \over { - 1}}}  = \sqrt { - 1}  = e^{\,\left( {i\pi  + i2k\pi } \right)/2}  =  \pm i}  \cr 
 }
$$